# Find a convergent solution for $a$

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, factorial

Find a value for $a$ in which the following sum *converges*. 
$$a+a!+(a!)!+((a!)!)!+\cdots$$
I know that there are no solutions if you only look at $a\in \Bbb{R}$, but are there any solutions if you extend your range (term used loosely) of possible answers to $a\in \Bbb{C}$? A rigorous proof is nice but ultimately not necessary to answer this question.

Comment: How do you define $a!$ in general? Gamma function?

Comment: @quid Yes, that is correct: $a!=\Gamma({a+1})$

Comment: What is your definition of $a!!$? Is it $(a!)!$? Because that's not the most [common definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Comment: @Arthur It is $(a!)!$ and not $a!!$. Thanks a bundle for pointing that out

Comment: Since the series is not convergent for any nonnegative integer $a$ you should probably restate the series in terms of the gamma function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum cannot converge, even for complex $a$. If an infinite series converges, the summands must tend to $0$. However, since each summand is the factorial of the previous summand, then the summands would also tend to $0!=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Nice and simple! This argument covers *any* continous (at $n=0$) extension of $n!$ from the integers to other real (or complex) numbers.